# Discord.js i make a warn command that write a file using FS

Tags: javascript, command, discord.js, fs

So when i warn a user it works perfectly, but when i try to warn again a person it replace the old string (the reason) but i want to make it add and keep the old string. (the reason) i tryed many things but still, fs is replacing automaticaly the old string (the reason).

And there is my javascript code :

```html
const Discord = require("discord.js")


const fs = require("fs");



module.exports = {
   name: "warn",
   description: "Warn command",
  async execute(  message){
    let config = require("../config.json")
    let lang = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./langs.json", "utf8"));
    
    if(!lang[message.guild.id]){
      lang[message.guild.id] = {
        lang: config.lang
      };
    }
    
    
    
    
        let correct1 = lang[message.guild.id].lang;
       
      
    
      const ping = require(`../lang/${correct1}/warn.json`)
      const response = ping
      const messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
      const args = messageArray.slice(1);
      let sEmbed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#FF0000")
      .setTitle("Permission refused.")
      .setDescription("<:dont:803357503412502588> | You don't have the permission for this command. (`MANAGE_ROLES`)");
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.reply(sEmbed1)
        
    const user = message.mentions.users.first()
    
     if(!user) {
      return message.channel.send("<:dont:803357503412502588> | You need to mention a user.")
    }
    if(message.mentions.users.first().bot) {
      return message.channel.send("<:dont:803357503412502588> | You can't warn a bot")
    }
    if(message.author.id === user.id) {
      return message.channel.send("<:dont:803357503412502588> | You can't warn yourself!")
    }
    const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")

  if(!reason) {
      return message.channel.send("<:dont:803357503412502588> | You need a reason")
    }
  
 
  
      
   const warnings = {
    reason: `${reason}`,
      guild_id: `${message.guild.id}`,
      user_id: `${user.id}`,
     
      moderator: `${message.author.username}`
   }
   const jsonString = JSON.stringify(warnings)
    fs.writeFile('./warnings.json', jsonString, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error writing file', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully wrote file')
        
    }
})


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(warnings)
>     fs.writeFile('./warnings.json', jsonString, err => {
>     if (err) {
>         console.log('Error writing file', err)
>     } else {
>         console.log('Successfully wrote file')
>         
>     }
> })
> ```

Could you replace line 2 with `fs.writeFileSync("./warnings.json", jsonString, {'flags': 'a'}, err => {`

Comment: I did it but still when i try to warn the first time it write it but when i try to warn again it replace and remove the old one (the first warn)